# How to make javascript ignore escape ( \ ) character?

Tags: javascript, escaping

```
qAnswersR[90430] = [];
    qAnswersR[90430].push("[math]k: \frac{(x+20)^{2}}{256}+\frac{(y-15)^{2}}{81}=1[/math]");
```

And I need to get the value into variable, but when I console.log out the array like this:

```
console.log(qAnswersR[90430]);
```

I get: **`[math]k: rac{(x+20)^{2}}{256}+rac{(y-15)^{2}}{81}=1[/math],[math]k: 81(x+20)^{2}+256(y-15)^{2}=20736[/math]`**

But the escape tag `"\"` disappears, but I need it there, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***But the escape tag "\" disappears, but I need it there, what should I do?***

You need to escape the backslash, i.e., use `\\` instead of just `\`:

```
"[math]k: \\frac{(x+20)^{2}}{256}+\\frac{(y-15)^{2}}{81}=1[/math]"
          ^                       ^
```

Comment: Ok thx, what do you think would be the best function in php to do that? since the script is generated in php. (addslashes?)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines

Answer (score 6):

You can use tagged template literals

```
var str = (s => s.raw)`[math]k: \frac{(x+20)^{2}}{256}+\frac{(y-15)^{2}}{81}=1[/math]`[0]
```

The anonymous arrow function will serve as tag and `s.raw` contains the original input

Answer (score 4):

Escape the escape character, like `\\a`.