# How to ignore escape characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode

I have the following string:

```
var str = '\x27';
```

I have no control on it, so I cannot write it as '\\x27' for example. Whenever I print it, i get:

```
'
```

since 27 is the apostrophe. When I call `.length` on it, it gives me 1. This is of course correct, but how can I treat it like a not escaped string and have it print literally

```
\x27
```

and give me a length of 4?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184453/how-to-make-javascript-ignore-escape-character

Comment: No it's not. The proposed solution in that question is "You need to escape the backslash, i.e., use \\ instead of just \:" and I explicitly stated right in the second line of my question that I cannot do that, so it's a different question for a different context.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? - `str` is `'` and nothing else, it does not matter how it was assigned to.  If you want to print 4 you would need to apply a logical test;  `len = str == "'" ? 4 : str.length` - Or are you asking how to derive an escape sequence form a char?

Comment: @AlexK http://adventofcode.com/day/8

Comment: So given `var a = "'", b = "\x27";` you want a way to determine that `b` exists in the source as an escape sequence as opposed to a literal?

Comment: No, given a = "\x27" I want to treat it as a four chars string starting with a '\', followed by an 'x' and '2' and '7, not like "'".

Comment: The only way to do this would be to parse them out of the source code itself with a regex, the escape sequence string simply does not exist at runtime

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you should do what you are trying to do, but this is how it works:

```
var s = '\x27';
var sEncoded = '\\x' + s.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
```

`s` is a string that contains one character, the apostrophe. The character code as a hexadecimal number is 27.

Comment: Doesn't this work only for this specific use case? What if you don't know the contents of the variable holding the string, but still need to escape characters.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, the solution shown only solves this particular problem. But of course you can generalize it and replace all the characters in the string with their char codes in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

After the assignment `var str = '\x27';`, you can't tell where the contents of `str` came from. There's no way to find out whether a string literal was assigned, or whether the string literal contained an escape sequence. All you have is a string containing a single apostrophe character (Unicode code point U+0027). The original assignment could have been

```
var str = '\x27'; // or
var str = "'"; // or
var str = String.fromCodePoint(3 * 13);
```

There's simply no way to tell.

That said, your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to print `\x27` in the first place?